# Небесная механика в XNA

Tags: c#, xna

Собрался делать космическую игру в 2D на XNA. C# изучаю недавно, параллельно с созданием совершенствую навыки программирования.

Для космической игры нужно? чтобы игра знала законы небесной механики - чтобы можно было сделать планету, выходить на орбиту, лететь к другим планетам и т.д. Хотелось бы знать, как именно сформулировать в `XNA` эти законы.

Comment: Вывести зависимости траекторий объектов от времени? при этом формулы выводить из особенности того что у нас всегда есть delta t.

Comment: Меня интересуют не сами законы, а то, как их внедрить в XNA. Реализацию гравитации я видел только в виде перемещения объекта вниз. Мне бы хотелось узнать, как перемещать объект не вниз, а по направлению к определенной точке.

Comment: @SkaterFromHell Вы только что угробили интерес вопроса =\

Answer (score 13):

- Небесная механика ничем не отличается от обычной механики. У объектов есть мгновенные параметры - **координаты, скорость, ускорение.**

> - На ускорение влияет набор сил, действующих на объект. В случае "земной механики" мы пренебрегаем силами притяжения от других планет ввиду малости массы земных объектов и большой величины расстояния (формула `F = G m1 m2 / R^2`) и учитываем только эту силу для планеты Земля.
> - В случае небесной механики это условие *"выворачивается"* - например, когда космический корабль пролетает рядом с Юпитером, нужно учитывать силу притяжения от Юпитера, но уже можно пренебрегать силой притяжения Земли.

- Взаимодействие планет и их движение по орбитам опять же определяется тем же самым соотношением из закона всемирного тяготения:

> Для упрощения подсчетов можно установить для каждой планеты ее фиксированную эллипсоидную орбиту и сформулировать функцию `(x, y, z) = F(t)`, определяющую положение планеты в произвольный момент времени с хорошим приближением к реальности.

- Осталось только обдумать движение космических объектов в вакууме вдали от всех планет:

> - Здесь все тривиально - объект без двигателей будет продолжать свое движение с заданным вектором скорости до достижения точки, в которой на него начинает *существенно* влиять какая-либо планета или спутник.
> - Под *существенностью* подразумевается невозможность пренебречь соответствующей величиной.

- Если понимать физические принципы, то реализовать это должно быть несложно как на `XNA`, `CryEngine`, `Unreal Engine`, так и на любом современном движке промышленного масштаба.
- **P.S.** Стоит отметить, что все вышенаписанное верно только в предположении скоростей, много меньших скорости света в вакууме.

> Если по каким-либо причинам вы собираетесь *качественно* моделировать ситуации, где скорости сравнимы со скоростью света, то имеет смысл обратиться [**к теории СТО / ОТО.**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)

Comment: }}}P.S. Стоит отметить, что все вышенаписанное верно только в предположении скоростей, много меньших скорости света в вакууме.

И для скоростей близких к ним также верно. Как оказалось там действует такой же линейный закон сложения скоростей. Вот интересный факт, о котором мало кто знает. На спутниках GPS при проектировании заложили коррекцию времени с поправкой на релятивистский эффект.Они движутся с 1 космической так что нужно вроде как им подводить часы для синхронизации.

Оказалось не нужно. Время оказалось инвариантно к скорости движения.

Comment: Советский проект по расчету скорости движения Венеры по диску солнца, тоже зашел в тупик когда начали использовать релятивистские поправки. Только их отбросили - все сошлость.

Вообще теория относительность такая мутная штука и в ней столько постулатов (утверждений, которое нельзя проверить, а только принять на веру), что начинает сыпаться если вдруг оказывается что скорость распространения света переменная и также зависит от среды как скорость распространения звука. В воздухе одна, в воде другая. Фононная теория для твердых тел вообще оперирует виртуальными частицами, переносящими звук.

Answer (score 6):

(Вопрос, конечно, старый, но вдруг кому-то пригодится мой ответ)

Небесная механика в общем случае - очень сложная вещь (особенно при попытке обобщения на случай [`n` взаимодействующих объектов](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/N-body_simulations_%28gravitational%29)). Для того, чтобы считать точно, обычно используют разложение силовой функции для конкретной задачи в виде ряда, берут несколько первых слагаемых этого ряда (скорости определяют, подставляя силовую функцию в лагранжиан системы - все сложно). Если интересно, как это делается, можно посмотреть в [классическом учебнике Дубошина](http://astrolib.ru/library/duboshin_spravochnoe_rukovodstvo_po_nebesnoy_mehanike_i_astrodinamike_izd_2_1976.html). Но на самом деле, так вы игру еще не скоро напишете, потому что умрете на разложении силовой функции. Тем более, что точно в общем виде задачу трех тел, сформулированную еще во времена Пуанкаре, не научились решать до сих пор.

Я бы на вашем месте рассматривала объекты как частицы с точечной массой, ну и, например, попробовала реализовать просто ради интереса [алгоритм Барнса-Хата](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation). В остальных случаях проще всего начать с школьной кинематики и усложнять уже в процессе.